# struggling to implement RBAC in react, pages won't render after successful login

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, authorization, roles

Im trying to implement RBAC in my react app,
Im using nodejs for backend which works perfectly fine, and in react Im using vite and react-router-dom v6.
I decided to store the token and role retrieved from my server, in Session Storage for simplicity.
I have 2 roles in my app, "basic" and "admin", after I successfully logged in,
I redirect based the role retrieved from my server.
I have an HOC as "middleware", to check role permission in my route layout as well.
The redirection works fine, however, I get an empty page for both roles when I test it, which both of them should render a simple h1 tag..
What am I missing, or doing wrong in my implementation ?

My login page:

```
import {useState} from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

const Login = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate()
  const [input, setInput] = useState({
    email:"",
    password:""
  })

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    const {name, value} = e.target;
    setInput((prev) => ({
        ...prev, [name]:value
    }))
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(input);

    const url = "http://localhost:8080/auth/login";

    try {
        const response = await axios.post(`${url}`,
        input,
        {headers:{
            'content-type':'application/json'
        }}
        );

        console.log(response);

        if(response.status === 200) {
            console.log("ok");

          const token = response.data.token;
          const role = response.data.role
          console.log({"token":token, "role":role})


          sessionStorage.setItem('token', token);
          sessionStorage.setItem('role', role);

            if(role === "admin"){
              navigate('/admin');
            } else if( role === "basic") {
              navigate('/basic');
            } else {
              navigate('/login');
            }

        }
    } catch(error) {
        console.log({"error":error.response})
    }
  }


  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Log In</h1>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <p>email:</p>
            <input type="text" name="email" value={input.email} onChange={handleInputChange}/>
            <p>password:</p>
            <input type="text" name="password" value={input.password} onChange={handleInputChange}/><br/>
            <button type='submit'>Login</button>
        </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Login
```

My router layout in app.js file:

```
import {  } from 'react'
import './App.css'
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router'

import Access from './Auth/Access'

import Home from './pages/Home'
import Login from './pages/Login'
import Signup from './pages/Signup'
import Admin from './pages/Admin'
import Basic from './pages/Basic'
import { Error } from './pages/Error'



function App() {

  return (
    <div>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Home/>}/>
        <Route path='/login' element={<Login/>}/>
        <Route path='/signup' element={<Signup/>}/>
        <Route path='/basic' element={<Access role={'basic'}> <Basic/></Access>}/>
        <Route path='/admin' element={<Access role={'admin'}><Admin/></Access>}/>
        <Route path='*' element={<Error/>}/>
      </Routes>
    </div>
  )
}
export default App
```

My HOC that check the role in route, names as Access:

```
import { Navigate,Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

const Access = ({ role }) => {
  const userRole = sessionStorage.getItem("role");
  const token = sessionStorage.getItem('token');
  
  if (!token || (role && role !== userRole)) {
    // Redirect to login if token is not available or user role doesn't match
    return <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
  }

  // User has the required role or no role is specified, render the nested components
  return <Outlet />;
};

export default Access
```

I expected both paged to render with simple h1 tags, based on role redirection from login.

Admin page:

```
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
import React from "react"

const Admin = () => {
  return (
    <div>wecome to admin page</div>
  )
}

export default Admin
```

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
import React from 'react'

const Basic = () => {
  return (
    <div>welcome to basic page</div>
  )
}

export default Basic
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a lot of tweaking, I think Im finally was able to solve this problem..
I created an HOC to accept a role, then navigate the currently logged in conditionally.

here is my solution, but I will keep this post open in case someone will have a better solution then mine..

lets starts with my router layout in app.js file:

```
import {} from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router";

import Access from "./Auth/Access";

import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Login from "./pages/Login";
import Signup from "./pages/Signup";
import Admin from "./pages/Admin";
import Basic from "./pages/Basic";
import BasicSubPage from "./pages/BasicSubPage";
import BasicSecondPage from "./pages/BasicSecondPage";
import PublicNav from "./pages/PublicNav";
import Error from "./pages/Error";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>

      <PublicNav/>
      <Routes>
        {/* public routes */}
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />

        {/* basic protected routes */}
        <Route element={<Access role={"basic"}/>}>
          <Route path="/basic" element={<Basic/>}>
            <Route path="basicsub" element={<BasicSubPage/>}/>
            <Route path="/basic/basicsecond" element={<BasicSecondPage/>}/>
          </Route>
        </Route>

        {/* admin protected routes */}
        <Route element={<Access role={"admin"}/>}>
          <Route path="/admin" element={<Admin />} />
        </Route>

        <Route path="/error" element={<Error />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

as you can see, my HOC is named as "Access" that accept a role as prop.

here is "Access" component:
please note: this is a simple validation, as I wanted to keep things as simple as possible..

```
import { Navigate, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

const Access = ({role}) => {
  const token = sessionStorage.getItem("token");
  const userRole = sessionStorage.getItem("role");

  if(!token || token && !role.includes(userRole)) {
    return <Navigate to="/error" replace/>
  }
  
  return <div>
     <Outlet/>
  </div>;
}

export default Access
```

my login component remains the same, so no change there,
i added to sub pages for "basic" user , so when I can use "tab" layout to navigate between those 2 pages..

so here is my "basic" page, keep in note that the other pages has simple h1 tag rendered, so I didn't added them here..

basic page:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { getInfo } from "../utils/basicUtils";
import { useNavigate , NavLink, Outlet} from "react-router-dom";

const Basic = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const token = sessionStorage.getItem("token");

  const [personalData, setPersonalData] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!token) {
      sessionStorage.removeItem('token');
      sessionStorage.removeItem('role');
      navigate(0);
    }

    const getPersonalInfo = async () => {
      const url = 'http://localhost:8080/basic/info'
      const resp = await getInfo(`${url}`,token);
      
      if(resp.status === 403) {
        console.log("forbiden");
        sessionStorage.removeItem('token');
        sessionStorage.removeItem('role');
        navigate(0);
        navigate('/home');
      }
      setPersonalData(resp.data.personalInfo)
      console.log("success", resp.data.personalInfo);
    };

    getPersonalInfo()

    }, [token]);

    const logout = () => {
      sessionStorage.removeItem('token');
      sessionStorage.removeItem('role');
      navigate('/home')
    }


    return (
      // <NavLink className="Link"  to="/home">Home</NavLink>

      <div> 
      <h1>welcome {personalData.name}</h1>
      <button onClick={logout}>Logout</button>
        <nav>
          <NavLink to={"basicsub"}>basic-sub</NavLink>
          <NavLink to={"/basic/basicsecond"}>basic-sub-second</NavLink>
        </nav>
        <Outlet/>    
      </div>
    );
};
export default Basic;
```